# Why is bound_function.toString() not returning the original source code?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
function f(a){ return a }
var g = f.bind(null);
g.toString() // chrome:  function () { [native code] }
             // firefox: function bound f() { [native code] }
```

Is there some subtle reason why `g.toString()` is not returning the original source code?

Of course, I could easily "fix" that by overriding `Function.prototype.bind` but my question is: am I doing something stupid like opening some security hole with this?

```
var o_bind = Function.prototype.bind;
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
        var f = o_bind.apply(this, arguments);
        f.orig_func = this;
        return f;
}
function fsrc(f){
        return f.orig_func ?
                String(f.orig_func).replace(/^function/, '$& bound') :
                String(f);
}
```

Comment: Well, `.bind` returns a new function.

Comment: @FelixKling, you are correct, but `f.toString() != g.toString()` :) (the `bind` probably returns a native function that when called does the actual call to the original function with the relevant `thisArg`)

Comment: @Dekel indeed, that _is_ what it does. A simplified version of `bind` is to just return the following `function() { return f.apply(thisArg, arguments); }`. A full version is not that much different but would handle the partial allocation functionality.

Comment: @Dekel: *"but `f.toString() != g.toString()`"* Exactly. I usually don't expect two *different* functions to have the same source. Especially not a native vs a user defined function.

Comment: The same thing could be said about closures -- they're always a different function though sharing the same "code":

    function f() { return function(){ } }
    f()==f() // false
    f().toString()==f().toString() // true

What bothers me is the possibility that there may be some programming patterns that /rely/ on a bind() not leaking any info about the original into the new function.

Comment: @local_user there _might_ be, although I've not encountered any myself. The use-case for getting the source code for a function comes up quite rarely, so I'm curious why do you need it.

Answer (score 2):

[The spec says about `Function.protoype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring) (emphasis mine):

> If *func* is a Bound Function exotic object, then
>   Return an implementation-dependent String source code representation of *func*. The representation must conform to the rules below. **It is implementation dependent whether the representation includes bound function information or information about the target function.**

In other words, environments are free to include the source of the original function or not.

---

> am I doing something stupid like opening some security hole with this?

Given that `toString` returns a function's source code for "normal" user defined functions, probably not.